# R XML Bad Request php

Tags: r

I would like to scrape the contents of this web page using the XML package and htmlParse: http://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/p.php?f=products.  However the link I am passing to htmlParse gives me a Bad Request error. What am I missing?

Comment: can you please provide your code and error message as part of the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require(RCurl)
require(XML)
iburl<-'http://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/p.php?f=products'
ua<-'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0'
ibdata<-getURL(iburl,useragent=ua)
htmlParse(ibdata)
readHTMLTable(ibdata)
```

It looks like it is checking the user agent.